# Client machine cannot see server, non-domain

Tags: windows-7, networking, windows-server-2012-r2, workgroup

Windows 7 client machine cannot see the Server 2012 R2 machine.

- Network Discovery and File & Print Sharing are both on for the server.
- Both can ping each other.
- Client needs to access a licence file on the server.
- Both machines are part of the same Workgroup.

*EDIT (Comment from deleted answer):*

- I can browse the shares okay and then the server appears in the Network tree in File Explorer but when we browse away from the share, the server disappears again.
- They are on the same subnet.
- The Windows 7 client can RDP to the server okay.
- Both firewalls are configured as per default Windows settings.

Answer (score 0):

Is the computer on a domain with the proper workgroup?  See screenshots:
Click Change Settings.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, neither the server nor the client machines are part of a domain but they are all joined to the same workgroup.

Comment: Then the Share is working as expected.  Map the Share you referred to in your Question as a network drive...